# EF Core Expression Could Not Be Bound

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following entities:

```
public DbSet<WFPP> WFPPs { get; set; }
....
[Table("PlanningUnit")]
public class PlanningUnit
{
    public PlanningUnit()
    {

    }

    public int PlanningUnitId { get; set; } 
    public Region Region { get; set; }       

}


[Table("WFPP")]
public class WFPP
{
    public WFPP()
    {
        AgencyList = new List<PlanningUnit>();
    }

     public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<PlanningUnit> AgencyList;

}
```

I try to load the entities as follows:

```
      var test= _context.WFPPs.Where(x => x.Id==0).Include(x => x.AgencyList).ToList();
```

And I get the following error:

```
The expression '[x].AgencyList' passed to the Include operator could not be bound.
```

I cannot figure out what is causing this error, and I cannot seem to find much information online. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  I tested with console app you just need to add get and set.

  [Table("WFPP")]
    public class WFPP
    {
        public WFPP()
        {
            AgencyList = new List<PlanningUnit>();
        }

         public int Id { get; set; }

      ///    your are missing get and set 
         public ICollection<PlanningUnit> AgencyList { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Wow. One of those days. Sometimes it is hard to connect weird errors with simple things you are missing. Thank you so much!